# Is this a way to defeat elision to keep dtor side effects?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to make sure destructor side effects are retained in a function which is a candidate for RVO. My goal is to snapshot the stack at entry and exit and have the expected stack variables present. This code seems to work for C++11 without using compiler specific options but I don't know a way to do this in earlier versions without adding spurious instances of Test to create multiple return paths. Is there some technique and does this always work for c++11?

```
class Test {
public:
    int m_i;
    Test() { m_i = 0; cout << "def_ctor" << endl; }
    Test(const Test& arg) { this->m_i = arg.m_i; cout << "copy_ctor" << endl;}
    ~Test() { cout << "dtor needed for side effects" << endl; }
};

Test foo() {
    Test ret;
    return std::move(ret);
}

int main()
{
    Test x=foo();
}
```

Comment: I know that, at least historically, adding volatile to the instances forces the code to be run/memory addresses to be accessed.

Comment: Yes, RVO is only allowed for non-volatile objects, but making it volatile has other effects, and means the copy constructor needs to be able to copy volatile objects.

Comment: Can you do it with a template method of Test that returns its parameter?  So instead of `return ret` you'd write `return test.return(ret);`  Then you'd do your state inspection inside of the method "return".  It would be a template so it would return the type of its arg: `T return (T t) { ... }`. (Can't try this at the moment, but I will later and see if it works.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::move` isn't magic, it's just a function that returns a reference to its argument, so you should be able to do the same in any version of C++

```
template<typename T>
  const T&
  defeat_rvo(const T& t)
  { return t; }

Test foo() {
    Test ret;
    return defeat_rvo(ret);
}
```

I think you can also do it more directly, by just returning a reference:

```
Test foo() {
    Test ret;
    const Test& ref = ret;
    return ref;
}
```

The copy elision rules say that the local object can be constructed directly in the return value when the expression in the return statement is "the name of a non-volatile automatic object", which is not the case here, as it's a reference to the object, not the name of the object itself. I'm less certain about that case, but a cast should work:

```
Test foo() {
    Test ret;
    return static_cast<const Test&>(ret);
}
```

This definitely isn't the name of the object, or the name of an alias to the object, it's a cast expression.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to just put the return value in parentheses? i.e. `return (ret);`

Comment: &Jonathan Wakely, &Benjamin Lindley Using VS2015 U2 both the static cast and (ret) elides. I was hopeful the reference cast would work. Sigh.

Comment: `return (ret)` is not required to suppress copy elision, and often does not in practice.

Comment: The defeat_rvo() works as well as putting in a separate ref variable. No idea why the  static cast doesn't. Changing the static cast to `static_cast<Test&&>(ret)` does work (it's pretty much what move does) but isn't portable to old C++.

Comment: I'm wrong. Just doing a `static_cast<Test&&>(ret)` doesn't work in VS2015. It has to be passed into a function and returned function arguments aren't elided according to the standard Looks like that is the best solution so far. I'll see what ideas people come up with and check back.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return an object you do not want to be elided; any such change is going to be fragile under future maintenance or refactoring.

In general, an object should support elision in the cases where it can occur; this places semantic restrictions on what a move or copy construction can be, and what a destructor does.

Violating these semantic restrictions is easy (`template<class T> T copy_of(T const& t){return t;}`, then `return copy_of(whatever);`, or a `static_cast`, or whatever).  It being easy does not mean it is safe, from a code maintainability perspective.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment but on occasion I need to instrument a function to examine the auto variables on the stack when it exits so I'm looking for a safe way to do this. Of course the way such variables appear on the stack is implementation defined but that's something one has to live with.

Comment: @doug then write a scope guard class?  Why associate it with the return value?

Comment: Would a scope guard (very cool technique) prevent "ret" from being instantiated in calling routines and so not appearing in the current functions stack frame?